# How to enable only tor connection on opensuse and monitor traffic?

Tags: linux, tor, internet

Is there any program or way to enable only secure tor connection on opensuse and like if I accidentally open my normal browser it wouldn't connect.

Also is there a program with which I can monitor my network traffic in real time so I can verify that it's working. Like which program is connecting to what ip and if it's not using internet at all. Thanks in advance.

I tried using the built-in YAST-Firewall but didn't find it quite useful.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, but you wouldn't like it. Tor is extremely slow even for just browsing modern Web pages, and even more so for anything else. Its high latency and propensity to lose packets make it unsuitable for live bidirectional communications, for example. To make matters worse, Tor has been proven to be not as secure as we all would like it to be -- especially if you're using it to circumvent government surveillance.

That being said, Tor's Wiki has a guide to help you enable transparent proxy (see the original [here](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TransparentProxy)):

1. Open your Tor configuration file (`/etc/tor/torrc` in OpenSUSE) with superuser powers to add the following lines:

   ```
   VirtualAddrNetworkIPv4 10.192.0.0/10
   AutomapHostsOnResolve 1
   TransPort 9040
   DNSPort 53
   ```
2. In order to redirect DNS requests via Tor, open your `/etc/resolv.conf` file with superuser privileges and replace whatever is in it with this single line:

   ```
   nameserver 127.0.0.1
   ```
3. Write an `iptables` script that prevents packets destined to your local network from getting redirected to Tor. In the following example, `192.168.0.0/24` and `192.168.1.0/24` are local networks:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh

   ### set variables
   #destinations you don't want routed through Tor
   _non_tor="192.168.1.0/24 192.168.0.0/24"

   #the UID that Tor runs as (varies from system to system)
   _tor_uid="109"

   #Tor's TransPort
   _trans_port="9040"

   ### flush iptables
   iptables -F
   iptables -t nat -F

   ### set iptables *nat
   iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner $_tor_uid -j RETURN
   iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 53

   #allow clearnet access for hosts in $_non_tor
   for _clearnet in $_non_tor 127.0.0.0/9 127.128.0.0/10; do
     iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d $_clearnet -j RETURN
   done

   #redirect all other output to Tor's TransPort
   iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --syn -j REDIRECT --to-ports $_trans_port

   ### set iptables *filter
   iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

   #allow clearnet access for hosts in $_non_tor
   for _clearnet in $_non_tor 127.0.0.0/8; do
     iptables -A OUTPUT -d $_clearnet -j ACCEPT
   done

   #allow only Tor output
   iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner $_tor_uid -j ACCEPT
   iptables -A OUTPUT -j REJECT
   ```

You're pretty much done. You might want to make a few adjustments, depending on your particular needs. For example, you might want to remove `iptables -F` and `iptables -t nat -F` if you have other NAT forwarding rules set up.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using iptables and the user module.

Since the tor daemon usually is run as the user "tor", we can make use of the iptables module owner to filter outbound traffic based on user uid.

In this example, we will drop all traffic that is not initiated by the user which is running the tor daemon.

First, lets lets assume that you start with a empty firewall policy.
You want this one to have a default policy to drop all traffic.

```
iptables -P INPUT drop
iptables -P OUTPUT drop
iptables -P FORWARD drop
```

Now, you want to accept inbound traffic which is related to an established connection. Note that you can only perform filtering based on usernames on outgoing traffic. You do not have control over packets sent from the internet.

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Allow traffic on the loopback interface. This will allow you to connect to the tor socks daemon running on port 9050.

```
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
```

And finally, you will have to allow traffic from the user "tor".

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -o inet-iface -m owner --uid-owner tor-uid -j ACCEPT
```

Replace inet-iface and tor-uid with the interface you are connecting to internet with, and the uid of your tor user.

Voila, all traffic which is not related to Tor should now be blocked.