# Tor, Tor Browser, iptables

Tags: linux, iptables, privacy, tor

I want to restrict my connections to Tor and Tor Browser.

Here at superuser I found [a good guide](https://superuser.com/a/1001050).

1. I'd like to add here Tor Browser. Is it possible?
2. Probably, it's a good idea to synchronize time also (Tor needs it).
3. Usually, I route apps to Tor by changing their proxy settings (to 127.0.0.1:9050/9150). Sometimes, when a program has no such option, I use torify. Probably, there should be other methods, via iptables. (?)
4. There are [many methods](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo#Configuration_on_startup) to keep iptables settings after restart. I need to connect to WiFi first. Which is the best, in this context? :)

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to add here Tor Browser. Is it possible?

Tor Browser only communicates with the tor daemon. Allowing the browser to directly access Internet would defeat the whole point of your setup.

> Probably, it's a good idea to synchronize time also (Tor needs it).

Time synchronization uses the NTP protocol (UDP port 123).

> Usually, I route apps to Tor by changing their proxy settings (to 127.0.0.1:9050/9150). Sometimes, when a program has no such option, I use torify. Probably, there should be other methods, via iptables. (?)

There are wrappers such as `torsocks` (aka `torify`) Running e.g. `torify ssh ...` will force it to use Tor, without affecting all other programs.

It is possible to use tor in "transparent proxy" mode for the entire system (this involves iptables).

> There are many methods to keep iptables settings after restart. I need to connect to WiFi first. Which is the best, in this context? :)

Your distro's provided service (e.g. `iptables.service` or `netfilter-persistent`) is fine.

What you need is to add firewall rules which allow you to connect – specifically, DHCP.

Comment: 'Tor Browser only communicates with the tor daemon.' -- thanks, always suspected it, but wasn't sure.

Comment: '(UDP port 123).' -- Is it a good idea, to leave some ports open (for everything)? Sophisticated malware could use it, probably.

Comment: So, my idea, in short, to create a group (a), (b) to allow it out (b), (c) to add to this group tor, and [name of time app] & [name for network manager]. Is it a correct idea? :)